# Error Copying Existing Audio File to Another Destination

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I recorded a file using `AVAudioRecorder` and I can play this file very well. I save this audio file with name "**MyAudioFile.m4a**". When I check this file exist or not using File Manager I get the true value means this file exist in device file manager.

> Problem is that when I try to copy this file on desktop it gives an
>   error.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String  

let getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingString("/MyAudioFile.m4a")
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if (filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(getImagePath))
{
    // Control always come in if block
    print("FILE AVAILABLE");
    try!  filemgr.copyItemAtPath( getImagePath , toPath: "/Users/talnetlgia/Desktop/songAudioFile.m4a")
}
else
{
    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
}
```

**Error:**

> 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “MyAudioFile.m4a” doesn’t
>   exist."
>   UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B715607-434A-47F9-9557-20CBDE34FC18/Documents/MyAudioFile.m4a,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Copy ), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/talnetlgia/Desktop/songAudioFile.m4a,
>   NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B715607-434A-47F9-9557-20CBDE34FC18/Documents/MyAudioFile.m4a,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x130001d80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2
>   "No such file or directory"}}: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.1.101.15/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 50`

Please help me I spent much time over it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that file exists, but it's getting the error while finding it! Just try to `print` the error:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingString("/MyAudioFile.m4a")
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if (filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(getImagePath))
{
    // Control always come in if block
    print("FILE AVAILABLE");

    do{

         try filemgr.copyItemAtPath( getImagePath , toPath: "/Users/talnetlgia/Desktop/songAudioFile.m4a")

     }catch let error as NSError {

         print(error.description)
     }
 }
 else
 {
     print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
 }
```

Comment: Erro-----> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “MyAudioFile.m4a” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1D37F8CE-6C92-4337-BA4A-3297B3342B6E/Documents/MyAudioFile.m4a, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/talnetlgia/Desktop/songAudioFile.m4a, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1D37F8CE-6C92-4337-BA4A-3297B3342B6E/Documents/MyAudioFile.m4a, NSUnderlyingError=0x13c725380 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: @vikranttanwar That's not an error! That's a crash. Try to replace your code with mine and here you will get the `print(error.description)` error

Comment: AS per your error, it means you are not getting the file from the `FileManager`

Comment: I replaced with your code and  this output comes from print(error.description).

Comment: I am not able to getting that if error showing no existence of file then how control comes into If block.

Comment: Why don't you try to copy at other destination rather than copying to your desktop. I hope copying outside bundle will not work. @vikranttanwar

Comment: Because I want to access this file and pass .m4a file to draw Wave form.